# Hijacking listeners in Java, passing in additional parameters

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I am building a simple app and I am implementing it in a simple MVC pattern where the controller adds event handlers to the view. Here's a sample controller code attaching a handler to the UI.

Basically, the code adds an event handler when the UI's save button is clicked. The UI contains the name and id number entry. What I wanted to happen is to pass the name and id number into the `actionPerformed` function.

```
ui.onAddStudent(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.print("test");
    }
});
```

And the receiving function in the UI (in another file) is the following.

```
public void onAddStudent(ActionListener handler){
    //something missing here
    addStudent.addActionListener(handler);
}
```

I am not really into Java because it's not my forte. I actually do JavaScript. Now, a similar handler In JavaScript, one can use the `call()` or `apply()` method to call the handler *and* pass in additional parameters. If the above code was in JS, it would be like

```
//in the controller
ui.onAddStudent(function(event,id,name){
    //I can use id and name
});

//in the UI
ui.onAddStudent = function(handler){
    //store into a cache
    //add handler to the button
}

//when student is added (button clicked)
handler.call(this,event,id,name);
```

How do I do the same thing in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

- let it as it is, and have the controller get the ID and name from the GUI (and that is the easiest and simplest solution, IMHO)
- use your own Event and Listener types, containing this information. For example:

  ```
  public class StudentAddedEvent {
      private long ID;
      private String name;
      ...
  }

  public interface StudentAddedListener {
      void studentAdded(StudentAddedEvent event);
  }
  ```

The UI would register an ActionListener on the button, and this action listener would do:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    long id = getIdInGui();
    String name = getNameInGui();
    StudentAddedEvent event = new StudentAddedEvent(id, name);
    for (StudentAddedListener listener : studentAddedListeners) {
        listener.studentAdded(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently testing out the first option since the controller does have reference to the UI. I'll get back when I get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own `Action`s too, and set those to the buttons (constructor argument or setAction) and other components.

Extend AbstractAction for that.